# Is there a command-line alternative to usb-creator-gtk?

Tags: boot, command-line, live-usb, usb-creator

I'm trying to create a bootable USB stick of ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso using usb-creator-gtk on my ThinkPad X220.  Usb-creator-gtk appears to work OK, but the resulting stick fails to boot either of my laptops.  I tried two different USB sticks.  Boot just shows a blinking cursor.

If I mount the USB stick, I see it has 729M of data on it.

One more clue: After usb-creator-gtk exits, the activity light on my USB drive continues to blink for a minute or so, and even after that's done, /media/XXXX-XXXX and /tmp/tmpXXXXXX remain mounted.  I have been manually umounting them before pulling out the stick.

Is there any way to get debug output from usb-creator-gtk?  Or is there a straightforward command-line alternative to usb-creator-gtk that would offer more debugging options?

UPDATE: In syslog, I noticed the error:

```
usb-creator-gtk[xxxxx]: segfault at 4 ip xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx sp xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx error 6 in libdbus-1.so.3.5.7[xxxxxxxxxxxx+xxxxx]
```

Turns out this is [ubuntu bug #875758](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/875758).

Is there an alternative to usb-creator-gtk?  Ideally, a bash recipe that would help me isolate the problem and work around it?

Comment: Have you tried unetbootin - I find this far better that the default in Ubuntu: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Also copying the ISO image to USB drive (not partition) with `dd` should work.

Comment: Thank you, fossfreedom.  Unetbootin worked where usb-creator-gtk failed.

Comment: @fossfreedom want to add that as an answer?

Comment: @Stefano - not really - I dont think it answers the question directly.  The OP seems to have disappeared - possible this question could be considered as abandoned?

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/875758) and as such is now closed.

Comment: Reopened Reopened

Answer (score 6):

- Identify device (`/dev/xxx`) and unmount device
- Device should be in FAT32 if not:

  ```
  sudo mkdosfs -n 'USB-LABEL' -I /dev/xxx -F 32
  ```

Mount the iso file and copy content to USB device:

```
sudo mkdir /media/iso
sudo mount -o loop /path/to/ubuntu.iso /media/iso
cp -a /media/iso/. /USBMOUNTPOINT/
```

Make the device bootable:

```
sudo apt-get install syslinux mtools
syslinux -s /dev/sdd1
```

Rename the `isolinux` directory to `syslinux` and copy config:

```
mv /media/xxx/isolinux /media/xxx/syslinux
mv /media/xxx/syslinux/isolinux.cfg /media/xxx/syslinux/syslinux.cfg
```

Reboot your pc and change the boot-order in bios to USB. Now your ubuntu usb flash drive will booted up and you can install it.

Comment: will the USB have persistent storage?

Comment: @CiroSantilli no, but you can manually create a casper-rw file (see http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-create-a-larger-casper-rw-loop-file/) and enable it by adding `persistent` to the kernel command line in `syslinux/txt.cfg`.

Comment: I tried this, but booting fails with boot error.

Answer (score 2):

### mkusb-nox wraps a safety belt around dd

It is possible to use *dd* 'naked', but I would discourage you to do it, because it is risky.

```
dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdx
```

*dd* is very powerful and does what you tell it to do without any questions, even if you tell it to overwrite your family pictures. A simple typing error is enough ...

***mkusb-nox*** is a tool, that works in text screens and terminal windows (nox: no X graphics).

It uses *dd* under the hood to clone the content of a hybrid iso file to a target block device (USB drive, memory card ...). Most current linux iso files are hybrid iso files. You can say that mkusb-nox (as well as mkusb with a GUI) 'wraps a safety belt' around *dd*.

***mkusb-nox*** uses an extraction method to create install drives for Windows.

See these links,

- [mkusb - general web page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
- [mkusb-nox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/v7)

---

### Edit: You can use dus (mkusb-dus) in text mode

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dus mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

- with the text mode interface (menu) dialog
- with a plain command line text interface
- [mkusb version 12 - Merged to a common version again - 'dus'](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Merged_to_a_common_version_again_-_.27dus.27)
- [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso/929586#929586)
- [How to install Ubuntu 16.10 without any gui?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872812/how-to-install-ubuntu-16-10-without-any-gui/872838#872838)

Comment: mkusb-nox is great! It's better than usb-creator-gtk

Comment: @diyism, I'm glad that mkusb-nox works well for you. Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: `dd` did not work for my Windows 11 Disk Image (ISO).  My computer complained it could not boot from the EFI device.  I had to use this rather laborious process instead: https://nixaid.com/bootable-usb-windows-linux/

Comment: @Joe, Cloning works for most Linux iso files, but not for Windows, so yes, you must use some other method. May I suggest another method, that might be easier than the one you found: [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) (not `mkusb-nox`, but **`mkusb-dus` and `mkusb-plug`** have GUI interfaces, that **call the text mode shellscript `mkusb-tow`** 'to Windows'). **You can use `mkusb-tow` directly from the command line (in text mode)**.