# BusyBox on persistent USB Livesystem

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, uefi, initramfs

I retried to build my persistent Linux USB stick, now Ubuntu 16.04 is out. But still it boot only to a busyBox prompt when using the persitent boot entry:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinux.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubunutu.seed boot=casper verbose persistent ramdisk_size=4294967296 keyb=de locale=de_DE no_splash ---
```

I have four partions:

- 100 MiB FAT32 ESP
- 2 GiB FAT32 for the sqashfs
- 1 GiB SWAP
- ~ 12 GiB for peristent data

My problem is that `mount -n -o move /dev {rootmnt}/dev` fails with:

```
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root : error 0
```

*How should I proceed?*

There are news to this question. I can refine it now and I found a start of an anwser. The Problem is located around the bootfiles not going into the ESP as they are intended to be installed there. Can confirm that [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/684547/505621) is related, but doesn't answer this problem. I found that problem was caused by my failure to install all bootfiles nessary into the ESP. I create a specifice question about a possible sulution attempt [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/793122/505621) to not clutter up this question as I was try to repair my mess on my own.
@videonauth pointed me to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768970/how-to-make-persistent-live-ubuntu-of-16-04/769124#769124) in chat, but it has to be converted for using with UEFI boot.

Feel free to help me to straiten up this question if you find doubleings or coment to provide questions about information that can help you and me to anwser my question.

Comment: I upgrade to a second 4 GiB pendrive (non-perstistent) with ubuntu 16.04 and recreated the perstistent one with this live system. If I start it non-perstistent it boots fine to desktop, but it auto configs to us keyboard layout. but if I use the perstistent boot entry it fails on initramfs to move to root.

Comment: Following things are still, the last entries on stdout: cp: can't create '/root/var/log/': Is directory cp: can't create '/root/etc/': Is directory    done.    Begin: Running 7scripts/nfs-bottom ... done   Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory   done.   mount: mounting /run on /root/run failed: No such file or directory   run-init:current directory on the same filesystem as root: error 0   Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.   run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as root: error 0 5 lines

Comment: I switched to building it within Ubuntu it self meanwhile, but that seemed to been not noticed (I edited It also not futher yet). but I created a more general one here: [Busybox on persistent USB Livesystem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286740/busybox-on-persistent-usb-livesystem "Question on Linux general SE")

Comment: Now, I know how to make it persistent, the problem, is another one, it boots to busybox, altrough it souldn't from all I know. The linked question also contains no new information.

Comment: I worked around  by installing the system to the stick for now. But I would appriate a solution for that way anyway. No answer as it don't solve the question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster you are welcome.

Comment: FYI: If you put the casper-rw partition on a second thumb drive persistence will likely work...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what causes the boot to terminate in a *busybox*/*initramfs* prompt but I can provide you with an alternate solution that does not involve installing Ubuntu to USB and still gives true persistence.

Try to use the `mkusb` tool to make your persistent USB system.

Detailed instructions are given [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/815493/585316).

Complete documentation+working can be found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb