# How to make a live usb persistent

Tags: 16.04, live-usb, persistence

I am running a live CD with Ubuntu 16.04 and I am trying to create a persistent image on a usb.  I have tried everything, but nothing is working.  I am on a Toshiba satellite c-50 b. 
 Please help, it is important.

Comment: It would help other if you mention what you have tried till now

Comment: You also can have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/768970/how-to-make-persistent-live-ubuntu-of-16-04/769124#769124)

Comment: Logically, your problem is insoluble - nothing is left to try if you have already tried "everything".

Answer (score 44):

I too have previously tried many different instructions without success and had almost given up when I found a working method using the very nicely created `mkusb` tool.

## Prior Considerations

I am assuming you have the .iso file (of Ubuntu 16.04) already downloaded. If not get it.

I have tried running these instructions from a Live USB stick so they should work from a LiveCD as well. 
Note that the USB stick I am live booting from is different from the one I intend to make as a persistent system. I.e. I have 2 USB sticks:

1. The one I am booting from (it has Ubuntu 16.04 already)
2. The one I am about to make a persistent live USB.

## Installing `mkusb`

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following commands one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mkusb
```

The last command might fail (though unlikely) as `mkusb` (**GUI** version) has some dependencies that are not preinstalled/active in the live version of Ubuntu.

No need to panic though, the developer has also created a text only version. Run:

```
sudo apt-get install mkusb-nox
```

## Creating the persistent drive

I will focus on the main GUI version as that is the one I have used. So if you installed the default `mkusb` (GUI version) run:

```
sudo -H mkusb /path/to/iso/filename.iso p
```

For example I have copied my Ubuntu iso to the the home folder, so I type:

```
sudo -H mkusb ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso p
```

The last `p` parameter tells mkusb that I want a **persistent** live install. If you omit that you will get a simple live USB.

After you run the command the GUI will open.
Follow these steps next:

- **Screen 1:** Click *Select target device*
- **Screen 2:** Double-Click the device you want to install to.
- **Screen 3:** Double check you have selected the right device. Tick the check-box and click *Go*.
- **Screens 4, 5:** Just click quit and let `mkusb` decide what's best.

  After this `mkusb` will load some files. Wait patiently till the next input screen.
- **Screen 6:** Enter the percentage of USB drive space you want to allot for persistence file-system. The remaining will show up as portable storage device.

  <strike>**Note:** Do not enter a value like 100% as some memory will be required for the Ubuntu OS files.</strike> Apparently entering 100% now works. As mentioned in @LMB comment, using 100% means the entire USB is used for the OS and the persistent storage

Done!

## Screenshots

The whole process should look something like the following.

Run the command in terminal:

[image: Run command in terminal]

Click *Select target device*:

[image: Click "Select target device"]

Click on the USB drive to make persistent. I want to use my 32 GB one so I double click on option 2:

[image: Click on the USB drive to make persistent]

Double check very carefully and confirm. You don't want to mess up another drive.

[image: Double check and confirm]

Click quit to let `mkusb` choose default:

[image: Go with the flow]

Click quit to let mkusb choose default:

[image: Go with the flow]

Enter a percentage of the drive to reserve for persistence. Mine is a large (32GB) so I allot only 20% ~ 6GB:

[image: Enter percentage of drive for persistent files.]

If all goes well you will be greeted by a nice green finished screen:

[image: Finished Successfully]

Now plug your newly made persistent drive in any system and check if it really stores data/settings across reboots (Mine does).

## References

You can refer to a nice [tutorial](https://calvin.me/create-persistent-ubuntu-16-04-live-usb-even-boots-ram) by Calvin Bui [here](https://calvin.me/create-persistent-ubuntu-16-04-live-usb-even-boots-ram) to guide you through the GUI step by step or read through the detailed documentation 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb
There has been a previous discussion about it here https://askubuntu.com/a/753163/585316 which I found useful.

## Update [August 2017]

As of 01-August-2017 the current version of `mkusb` (ver 12) is renamed as `dus`. An updated version of this answer for `dus` is available here: https://askubuntu.com/a/853839/585316

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto@terdon Chill guys , I have now added more detailed explicit steps to my answer as I promised in my previous comment. Sorry for the delay, I had a long day and needed rest.  I had also prepared a  more tutorial-esqe version (which took time) with screen-shots etc but the site wont let me link/show images as I am new here.  Anyway please tell me if I can improve the answer further. Thanks.

Comment: This is an extremely good edit! If you need pictures just post their links as source code and ping me so I can insert them for you.

Comment: @Andrea Lazzarotto Thanks. I think the up vote to my answer got me enough points to let me attach multiple images. I have added them too in another edit.

Comment: does this work with 32-bit ubuntu as well?

Comment: @bvpx Yes. In-fact he screen-shots are from a 32-bit Ubuntu if I remember it right.

Comment: @Harsh I would like to make you aware of this new question which you seem qualified to answer: https://askubuntu.com/q/954691/346905

Comment: Used this method, it works. You can select 100% for the persistency. This means the entire USB is used for the OS and the persistent storage. If you leave this value below 100% you end up with an additional NTFS partition for use as a ´regular´ usb/drive.

Comment: I believe this answer has been very useful once. However it seems that `mkusb` has been redesigned quite a lot. So this answer is no longer useful out-of-the-box. An update is requested.