# 8GB usb become 1GB after installing ubuntu?

Tags: live-usb

I've just installed and booted to Ubuntu from my bootable USB, which is originally 8 GB USB.

Now when I'm looking at the USB size I can only find 1.1 GB partition?

Is Ubuntu really taking up 7 GB from my USB or am I missing something?

Comment: What Ubuntu image is it? How big is the image?

Comment: sounds about right if you installed

Comment: ubuntu is only using 1.1 GB of the 8GB the rest is unallocated.You can't see the rest, because the image was burnt without a partition table

Comment: How did you "install" Ubuntu exactly? You downloaded the ISO and "burned" it to the USB? Not really the same as installing, but you can allocate the rest of the space after booting into "Try Ubuntu" mode, to use for persistent storage.

Comment: @wjandrea it is Ubuntu 16.04.01, The ISO was ~1.5GB

Comment: @ravery In ubuntu it is shown as 1.1GB partition, with even less free space... In windows, it showed as 8GB with 6.5GB free space.

Comment: @dobey I installed it with rufus following this [link](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0). I have logged by using "Try Ubuntu" because I intend to use it as a portable OS.

Comment: If you're going to use it as a portable os, check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/772744/how-to-make-a-live-usb-persistent - setting it as a persistent one allows to access the space easily from within Ubuntu, for settings and documents. Otherwise, you can just create a partition in the unallocated space on the drive (using e.g. Gparted in Ubuntu, windows has tools for this too) to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partition on the USB drive is only as big as the Ubuntu image you burned to the drive. (I'm guessing the size is inconsistent because some things show it in megabytes and others in mebibytes.) The rest of the space would need to be partitioned before it's accessible; you could use GParted to do that.

Ultimately, where you want to set up a portable OS, you should refer to one of these questions, depending on your needs:

- Live image: [How to make a persistent live Ubuntu USB with more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/q/397481/301745)
- Full install: [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/q/16988/301745)