# can't mount any partitions from Live USB on HP Laptop

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a disk partition in a new HP laptop, but are unable to boot into it.
I found that there are issues with dual booting on HP machines using UEFI and some successful workarounds (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392797).

My problem is that when booting from an Ubuntu live USB, I'm unable to mount any of the partitions on the hard drive.

GParted throws this warning when started:
[GParted warning - space unused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep6Ao.png)

And all partitions cannot be mounted, with variations of `Unable to detect file system!` or  
`Unable to read the contents of this file system!`. [GParted - partitions list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Xrf.png)

This is what appears in the description of the Linux partition:

```
The device /dev/nvme0n1p3 doesn't exist

Failed to open '/dev/nvme0n1p3'.

The device /dev/nvme0n1p3 doesn't exist

Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support:  ntfs-3g / ntfsprogs.
```

This problem was happening also before the installation, but it seems to have gone through without error.

Comment: Are you dual booting with Windows 10 Pro?  Is the Windows install encrypted?

Comment: @walttheboss No to either, it's Win 10 Home

Comment: Do you have `ntfs-3g` package installed on your live USB? Note to do so your live USB would have to have been created with persistence.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix `ntfs-3g` was installed but somehow creating a live USB with persistence solved the problem

Comment: If you are amicable to the suggestion I'll create an answer after work and you can accept it as it could be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments the SSD partition attempting to mount is a Windows partition. For that to work you need `ntfs-3g` package installed. To successfully install packages to a Live USB it needs to be a persistent Live USB:

- [How to make a live usb persistent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772744/how-to-make-a-live-usb-persistent/815493#815493)
- [How to make a persistent live Ubuntu USB with more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb/438734#438734)