# Where are the syslinux x86-64 files located on a booted up live medium?

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, live-usb, syslinux

I found a problem during creation of a live USB stick with a ESP to boot from.
I have to populate the ESP manual.

Therefor I need to copy the files from /usr/lib/syslinux/efi64/ to the ESP. Althrough  syslinux and efibootmgr are installed (checked with apt_cache) the files seem to be not in the standart location.

Hope this question is easier to answer than my previos ones. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Having a stable temporary stytem to cross compile from is my intention.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package `syslinux-efi` first it is not preinstalled.

Than you can find the files below `/usr/lib/SYSLINUX.EFI/`

This package contains only the binary and not the divers *.c32 files for creating a bootmenu for example.