# "Try Ubuntu" from install USB - how to make it not erase files every time?

Tags: 18.04, live-usb

I like to use the "Try Ubuntu" feature from the live USB, but every time i log in to it, the account is reset and the files are gone. Is there a way i can make the files stay?

Comment: Depending on the way you create the USB, look for a way to make the live USB "persistent". See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/684547/how-to-create-a-persistent-usb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a live Ubuntu 18.04 USB with a persistent storage of more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051543/how-to-make-a-live-ubuntu-18-04-usb-with-a-persistent-storage-of-more-than-4gb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Full Install USB vs Persistent install

A Full install USB and a Persistent install USB both save data and installed programs after reboot.

**Comparison between Persistent and Full install USB**

**Advantages of a persistent install:**

1) You can use the persistent pendrive to install Ubuntu to another computer.

2) A persistent install takes up less space on the pendrive.

3) You can reset the pendrive by overwriting the old casper-rw file with a new one.

4) The install to pendrive takes less time.

**Advantages of a Full install:**

1) You can update and upgrade.

2) If you have problems or wish to modify, the solution is the same as with an internal install, (You can ask for help in these forums).

3) No ugly startup / install screen.

4) Better security, you can use full encryption

5) You can use proprietary drivers.

6) Hibernation works.

7) A persistent install is limited to a 4GB casper-rw and a 4GB home-rw persistence file, to get more persistence requires persistence partitions. Once casper-rw is full, the drive will not boot.

8) Faster boot.

9) You can run VBox and use virtual machines.

Note that once booted, both methods run at about the same speed.

**Full Install Method**

One method for creating Full install USB: [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 19.10 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-19-10-to-usb-device-step-by-step)