# Installing Ubuntu on a flash drive

Tags: usb

I would like to try Ubuntu, by installing it on a USB (flash) drive.  The instructions say I need a Ubuntu ISO file on my computer but when I follow the link given, the first option is "Install Ubuntu and REPLACE Windows"  Zounds!   I don't want that, there seems to be no option there that says "download the ISO file".  How do I do this?
  I have already installed Rufus and I am "all ready".  How about a clue.

Comment: The safest way to install Ubuntu into a flash drive (installed like into an internal drive but into a USB flash drive) is to first remove or disconnect or disable the internal drive. Otherwise you may end up with the bootloader (or the whole system) in the internal drive. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312) may be useful.

Comment: There are advantages to making a Persistent install to USB and advantages to making a Full install to USB. For details see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222532/try-ubuntu-from-install-usb-how-to-make-it-not-erase-files-every-time/1222797#1222797

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Ubuntu ISOs here:
[Ubuntu.com/download/desktop](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

After installing the ISO onto your flashdrive, plug the flash drive into your computer and boot from the drive (you may need to look up how to do so for your particular system, but repeatedly pressing the 'Delete' button should bring you to the BIOS menu, where you should be able to select your flash drive from the boot menu).

After successfully booting from your flash drive, it should present you with a screen like this:

[image: Try Ubuntu]

Simply select "Try Ubuntu" and nothing on your hard drive will be altered. Simply remove the drive and reboot and your Windows instance will resume as normal.