# How to install Ubuntu 16.10 without any gui?

Tags: command-line, system-installation, 16.10

I want to start my computer and it should open up to a CLI. I don't want a GUI, no fancy login screen etc.

I need a solution that does not use a minimal ISO because it requires an internet connection. I need an offline installation.

Comment: @muru i think it's not duplicate. he want solution "Without using minimal ISO because it requires internet connection".

Comment: @Bharat Middha do you want (boot start into command line and keep GUI installed) or (boot start into command line and remove GUI)? . PS: i mean "gui" here is "desktop environment"

Comment: I suggest ubuntu server edition. When is fails to acquire an IP address via DHCP, just accept and continue. See also [here](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/testcases/1441/info)

Comment: @ryan Then install as normal and dupe of http://askubuntu.com/q/16371/158442

Comment: @muru Or maybe remove GUI completely? https://askubuntu.com/questions/147858/how-to-remove-desktop-environments

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu Server. [Ubuntu Server 16.10](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)

Just download the ISO file and make a installation USB disk with [UltraISO](https://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/) or other tools, and install it on your computer offline.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it will work, based on the criteria of the question.  In the future, please consider using the comment for your question (`Do you mean Ubuntu Server`).  A proper answer would better be, (`Use the Server Install ISO`), which doesn't user or install **X**.  **X11** can be installed later if needed.

Comment: @L.D.James This gives a solution and is thus an answer, and it would not have been correct to post it as a comment. (When question-like text in an answer seems to cause genuine confusion, you can edit to rectify the problem.) Furthermore, we have a strong community consensus that [even if an answer attempt is incomplete or otherwise flawed, that still doesn't make it an appropriate comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2281). Before telling someone their answer should've been a comment, I recommend [consulting these official guidelines](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 4):

You can install Ubuntu 16.04.1+ LTS (up to date 2017-01-15) with [mkusb-nox or mkusb-dus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) in text mode **from a compressed image file** according to the following link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)

This picture shows what it looks like after log in.

[image]